# Is it possible to add default text to listGrid filter?

Tags: filter, smartgwt, listgrid

I have a listGrid with some data in it. Also, I filtered data programmatically (i.e. using filterData method). Now I want to show filter value, I set programmatically, to be visible to user. In other words, I want to show the value in the filter box. 
Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the content of the FilterEditor by

```
listGrid.setFilterEditorCriteria(myCriteria);
```

Please note that the OperatorId of myCriteria must match the OperatorId that is assigned to the fields of your listGrid (see ListGrid.setFilterOperator).